# Unable to set image on excel header using Apache poi

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I am using Apache Poi library for generating Excel template
i.e XSSFWorkbook and XSSFSheet but unable to set image on header.
Can any body help me on this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077404/apache-poi-adding-watermark-in-excel-workbook/51103756#51103756. The goal here is having a "Watermark" but this ist nothing else than a picture in the header here.

Comment: Post some code so that we can help