# Include an image to the right of a Header in Excel in Java using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to add image to the right side of Header in Excel in java using POI. Below is my sample code

```
private static void drawImageOnExcelSheet(XSSFSheet sheet, int row, int col, int height, int width, int pictureIdx)
        throws Exception {

    CreationHelper helper = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();

    Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

    ClientAnchor anchor1 = helper.createClientAnchor();
    anchor1.setAnchorType(AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

    anchor1.setRow2(row); // second anchor determines bottom right position
    anchor1.setCol2(col);
    anchor1.setDx2(Units.toEMU(width)); // dx = left + wanted width
    anchor1.setDy2(Units.toEMU(height)); // dy= top + wanted height

    Picture pic = drawing.createPicture(anchor1, pictureIdx);
    pic.resize();

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is the problem using your code? The code puts a picture in sheets drawing which is over the cells of the sheet. But the sheet header part is not on sheets drawing but is on a `VMLDrawing` instead. You want to put the picture in sheet's header part and not over the cells?

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting a stackoverflow reference in answer as i don't have privilege to comment.

See [apache POI adding watermark in Excel workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077404/apache-poi-adding-watermark-in-excel-workbook/51103756#51103756) for how to set an image as header content in Excel