# Apache POI - watermark in Excel - different appearence in Excel and LibreOffice

Tags: apache-poi

I follow the [sample](https://www.programmersought.com/article/86016100239/) and add pictures as watermark like the following:

```
private void addWaterMark4AllSheets() {
    final BufferedImage image = FontImage.createWatermarkImage();
    // Export to byte stream B
    final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", os);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook) workBook;
    final int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(os.toByteArray(), Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
    final POIXMLDocumentPart poixmlDocumentPart = wb.getAllPictures().get(pictureIdx);
    // ((XSSFSheet )(schreiben.getSheet()).
    for (int i = 0; i < workBook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {// Get each Sheet
        final XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);
        final PackagePartName ppn = poixmlDocumentPart.getPackagePart().getPartName();
        final String relType = XSSFRelation.IMAGES.getRelation();
        // add relation from sheet to the picture data
        final PackageRelationship pr = sheet.getPackagePart().addRelationship(ppn, TargetMode.INTERNAL, relType,
                null);
        // set background picture to sheet
        sheet.getCTWorksheet().addNewPicture().setId(pr.getId());
    }

}
```

In general the approach works quite fine. A picture is added into the Excel. But the appearance is different.

1. In Excel: the image is displayed in the background during the editing (of the sheets). But it is NOT displayed when I print the sheet.
2. In LibreOffice (7.1): the image is NOT displayed during the editing (of the sheet) - but is printed.

Is there a chance to fix it for working in both Spreadsheets?

Comment: Works as designed. What the code does is to add a graphic to the background of Excel worksheets. But that's not a watermark. And [You cannot print a background graphic for a Excel worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-cannot-print-a-background-graphic-for-a-excel-worksheet-7b1bbe1b-c672-a1bc-99e1-fb9eb8af5c45). See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-a-sheet-background-3577a762-8450-4556-96a2-cc265abc00a8 for how to mimic a watermark in Excel.

Comment: You have tested with Excel or LibreOffice? Excel which verison? Would be great to know - since I haven't installed a version... In Libreoffice it isn't shown.

Comment: Yeah, good to know that it works as designed. My question wasn't about this. My question was that Excel and Libreoffice display and treat the same result differently. Is there a chance to get them working both the same way? i.e. display AND printing the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing what `apache poi` could change as this behavior is by design in the different spreadsheet softwares.

Your linked code example does **not** creating watermarks. Watermark functionality is not available in Microsoft Excel. Instead it adds background pictures to sheets.

Microsoft itself states: [You cannot print a background graphic for a Excel worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-cannot-print-a-background-graphic-for-a-excel-worksheet-7b1bbe1b-c672-a1bc-99e1-fb9eb8af5c45). So using Microsoft Excel the sheets background graphics only are visible in Excel GUI but not in prints.

In LibreOffice those background graphics are called watermarks but Libreoffice states in [Defining Graphics or Colors in the Background of Pages (Watermark)](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/shared/guide/background.html?&DbPAR=WRITER&System=WIN):

> In spreadsheets this background appears only in the print behind the
> cells not formatted elsewhere.

So using Libreoffice the sheets background graphics are visible in prints only.

So what you had observed is by design.

In [Add or remove a sheet background](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-a-sheet-background-3577a762-8450-4556-96a2-cc265abc00a8) Microsoft describes methods to mimic a watermark in Excel. The usage of  a picture in a header or footer to mimic a watermark using `apache poi` is described in [apache POI adding watermark in Excel workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077404/apache-poi-adding-watermark-in-excel-workbook/51103756#51103756). But this also means a print watermark. So the watermark is visible in print preview and print only. It is not visible in sheet's GUI. And the option to add picture in a header or footer to mimic a watermark is Excel only. LibreOffice does not provide that feature.

Conclusion:

There is not a possibility to have a functionality similar to a watermark which works in Excel and LibreOffice the same way.

Comment: So, more or less my conclusion of what you write here is that the best approach is to add the picture as header/footer. Than I have some kind of mimiced watermark in Excel and LibreOffice.

Comment: @LeO: The option to add picture in a header or footer to mimic a watermark is Excel only. LibreOffice does not providing that feature.

Comment: Aha - thx this clarifies my request.... So, I need to test little bit further...